# ECPublicKey Serializability

Tags: java, serialization, bouncycastle

I am working on a project in which I need to pass generated public key ([`ECPublicKeyParameter`](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/ECPublicKeyParameters.html)) 
over the network between two parties. But I am having problems serializing it. How can I serialize an instance of this class?